# What is the fastest way to convert large HTML files to PDF?

Tags: html2pdf

I have an html page (with css styles) that is generated on click of a button. generated html+css needs to be turned into pdf.

I'm using html , css and js code. I tried jspdf plugin . But it is completely suitable for me. I'm looking for another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you want to convert PDFs client-side, Any client-side code is ineffective for doing that.

But I could recommend `html2pdfjet.com`. They are offering a very high-quality PDF that will also support all HTML attributes.